# How can tox install the modules via the requirements file?

Tags: python, tox

Our python project has a requirements.txt file which lists some dependent module. We used to use

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

to install these dependencies. We are now using tox to build up the test environment. My question is that how can we install the modules via requirements.txt directly.

Followings are our tox.ini and requirements.txt:

tox.ini:

```
[tox]
envlist=py27
[testenv]
deps=pytest
     boto
commands=py.test
```

rquirements.txt:

```
boto
```

Is any way to remove the "boto" from tox.ini and add something like

```
deps_files=requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
 deps = -r{toxinidir}/tools/pip-requires
        -r{toxinidir}/tools/test-requires
```

Comment: This has the issue that it will not auto update the virtualenv

Comment: @hangtwenty broken link. Updated link: https://caremad.io/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/

Comment: This gives me the error "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-eV81Ia-build/pip-requires'". The requirements files are not automatically copied by tox into its tmp build directory.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning you should have a `MANIFESTS.in` file that has the line `include requirements.txt`. This will ensure that our requirements file gets added to your distributed package. More information [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Distutils/Tutorial)

@Cerin I think this will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 40):

What helped me is the following (the other solution didn't work for me):

```
deps=
    pytest
    -r requirements.txt
```

This works at least if you add `requirements.txt` to `MANIFEST.in` and if you use a relatively new tox (>= 1.6.1) version ([see here](http://tox.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example/basic.html#depending-on-requirements-txt)).

Comment: Great help, thanks. Inclusion into `MANIFEST.in` is not required for simple call `$ tox`, but if you are using `$ devpi test`, inclusion is crucial.

Comment: Note, that **There shall be no space between `-r` and `requirements.txt`**. For me, a space prevented `requirements.txt` to install.

Answer (score 31):

I had already setup my dependencies as in the accepted answer above, however any new dependencies were not installed like they are when tox is run for the first time. To install new dependencies in the virtualenv I had to force tox to recreate the environment like so:

`tox --recreate -e py27`

[UPDATE: this issue should be fixed in `tox` v4]

Comment: According to https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/149 this is a know bug

Answer (score 15):

You can put dependencies and test dependencies in `requirements.txt` and `requirements.testing.txt` in order to the root directory.

Put `tox.ini` in your root directory of your project and you can use the approach below to install dependencies.

`[testenv] deps = -r{tox_ini_dir}/requirements.txt -r{tox_ini_dir}/requirements.testing.txt`

In addition to upgrade dependencies

`[testenv] deps = -Ur{tox_ini_dir}/requirements.txt -Ur{tox_ini_dir}/requirements.testing.txt`

Comment: `-Ur` is the right answer, as it makes sure you keep your dependencies up to date.